# Reduce stock Qty on StockIN table based on Order Stock table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

im confused with my stock logic on mySQL design that not working, I have `order_stock` table that contain list of ordered item, and qty. I want to reduce stock on `stock_incoming` table based on selected `stock_incoming` `id`. Example I have Stock A on `order_Stock` table with Qty 5, it will reduce quantity on `stock_incoming` table.I tried to relate `order_stock` to `stock_incoming` table, but now cant reduce QTY of stock_incoming table. Is there any error on my data flow logic?

Here is Diagram view and Spreadsheet example:
[Stock_IN_OUT_Sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OSl6Iq-gMInSaXntBNmlqfW9g68jzQkvPdTMqNzlg0A/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: ERD Design]

**Update**: For now I can only proccess selected material to order material but still cant figure out how to reduce the stock by `stock_in` id.
Here the code:

```
    public Order $order;
    public $selectedMat;

    public function save()
    {

        foreach ($this->selectedMat as $value) {
            $this->order->materials()->attach([$value['id'] => ['qty' => 
            $value['qty']]]);
        }
        $this->order->refresh();
        $this->emit('parent-refresh');
        $this->emit('closeModal', 'matmodal');
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide any relevant code you have?

Comment: Im sorry but im not yet implement this one into the code because logic still unclear,and i cant figure out how to implement it to code for now. Its already 5 days and still confuse me. I try to figure out again to implement this design to code tonight.